# Simple Guessing Game Program in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a very simple number guessing game as a first project. I want the player to have 5 guesses before they lose.

I'm having difficulty troubleshooting the bugs or coding mistakes.

```
 var num = Math.floor((Math.random(1,10) * 10) +1);
 console.log(num); //To check
 var counter = 5;
 while(counter > 0){
  function guess(){
  counter = counter-1
  var guess = prompt("You've got " + counter + " tries to guess the number.");
   if (num == guess){
     alert("That's the number!");
   }else if (guess != (int){
     alert("That's not a number...");
   }else{
     alert("Nice try");
   }
 }
}
alert("You lost.");
```

Comment: What bugs? What mistakes? You haven't described what isn't working. My first guess is that you didn't really want to define a function in a loop, but just call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0skh4t4r/

```
var num = Math.floor((Math.random(1, 10) * 10) + 1);
console.log(num); //To check
var counter = 5;

function guess() {
  var x = prompt("You've got " + counter + " tries to guess the number.");
  if (!x) return; // cancel the game
  counter--;
  if (num === parseInt(x)) {
    alert("That's the number!");
    return;
  } else if (isNaN(x)) {
    alert("That's not a number...");
  } else {
    alert("Nice try");
  }
  if(counter === 0) {
    alert("You lost");
  } else {
    guess(); // next try
  }
}

guess();
```